# ¿Cómo envío un Email cuando aprieto el botón crear de una vista en particular?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-2017

Mi duda es como hago para que cuando creo un registro en mi proyecto, automáticamente cuando aprieto el botón crear de envíe un correo a una dirección especifica con un mensaje en particular.

Comment: Hola! Muestra lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Gracias :)

Comment: @Csc99 No he intentado nada aun, porque no tengo idea de como hacerlo, necesito de tu ayuda

Comment: que lenguaje estas utilizando??